# How to fix PHP Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 1309 of 49151 bytes?

Tags: php, serialization

I saved my array like this :

```
$saveModel = base64_encode(serialize($classifier));

mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO model_latih(isi) VALUES('$saveModel')")or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($db));
```

Then  I try to take it from database with the following code :

```
$q = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM model_latih")or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));

$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
$row = $fetch['isi'];
$data = unserialize(base64_decode($row));
```

But it give this error :

> PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 1309 of 49151 bytes

I've compared the `serialize` and `unserialize`result by length. 

Those two strings are different. The `serialize` length is 255164, `unserialize` is 65535. Seems like it doesn't fully loaded . 

Anyone know what make it different ?

I hope someone can help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried without insert to and get from database? If it work, the problem with database insertion. Probably there is a character what breaks the insertion or the result maybe. Use ony json encode with ENT_QUOTES paramter.

Comment: yes, it works perfectly when I didn't insert and get from database. Could you give me some references ?

Comment: 65535 should ring a bell.  Your database columns is likely too narrow.  Mysql is truncating your string on insert.

Comment: @MattS I use BLOB to store the `serialized` data. But I don't set the length. Could you give a suggestion for me for the datatype and length ?

Comment: Okay, what is your column type? I guess its varchar with less length than required

Comment: @Peter I use `BLOB`

Comment: Ahh yes, that's the problem as MattS suggested also, because A BLOB can be 65535 bytes (64 KB) maximum. Use MEDIUMBLOB type.

Comment: @Peter So I have to change the column type ? What do you suggest to replace `BLOB` ?

Comment: ok, I will try it

Comment: `MEDIUMBLOB` can be better, it depends on what is the maximum excepted length of your future data :)

Comment: Thank you so much mate, now I can continue my work. I wish you a good day :D. Once again thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I changed the type of the column in the database from BLOB to MEDIUMBLOB.

I found out that:

```
BLOB can hold 65535 bytes (64 KB)
MEDIUMBLOB can hold 16777215 bytes (16 MB)
LONGBLOB can hold 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)
```